# How to invoke a shell script on remote machine from WSO2

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am wondering if there is a way to invoke a shell script on a remote machine using the existing message mediators in wso2/synapse.

Or should I write a custom mediator using JSch?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you could use the predefined language in wso2(js, Ruby or Groovy) to call shellscript using script mediator